# String with index conversion or array of numbers

Tags: c#

Why i can't convert this string to a number? Or how to make a array of numbers from this string.

```
 string str = "110101010";
int c = Int32.Parse(str[0]);
```

Comment: any compile or runtime errors?

Comment: "Error 1 Cannot convert type 'char' to 'string'"

Comment: Int32.Parse(str[i].ToString ())

Comment: @KacperŁukasik don't vandalize the post, please. you've completely changed the context now. I am going to rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to convert a binary string into its decimal representation.

For this you could make use of `System.Convert`:

```
int c = Convert.ToInt32(str, 2);
```

For the case that you want to sum up all the 1s and 0s from the string you could make use of `System.Linq`'s `Select()` and `Sum()`:

```
int c = str.Select(i => int.Parse(i.ToString())).Sum();
```

Alternatively if you just want to have an array of 1s and 0s from the string you could omit the `Sum()` and instead enumerate to an array using `ToArray()`:

```
int[] c = str.Select(i => int.Parse(i.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Disclaimer: The two snippets above using `int.Parse()`would throw an exception if `str` were to contain a non-numeric character.

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a string so `str[0]` returns a `char` and the `Parse` method doesnt take a `char` as input but rather a `string`.

if you want to convert the string into an `int` then you would need to do:

```
int c = Int32.Parse(str); // or Int32.Parse(str[0].ToString()); for a single digit
```

or you're probably looking for a way to convert all the individual numbers into an array which can be done as:

```
var result = str.Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()))
                .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Int32.Parse` accepts `string` argument, not `char` which `str[0]` returs.

To get the first number, try:

```
string str = "110101010";
int c = Int32.Parse(str.Substring(0, 1));
```